# Can I realistically move all templating to javascript for my webapp?

Tags: java, ajax, json, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a Spring-MVC based webapp with a JSP front end.  It is your basic CRUD app with various other management and reporting screens thrown in.

We are currently using JSP with JSTL for our view, but our designer doesn't know JSP so it's been a real pain to merge his design changes into the source.  Due to that, my recent thought has been that if we could just hand the entire UI over to him and let him implement it entirely in HTML/Javascript, making ajax requests for JSON data for the dynamic portions, we would be able to remove that entire merge process and just host his static HTML files.  Development for him would be simple as he would be able to hit our REST webapp on our test server for sample JSON data using jsonp.

If the designer is proficient with javascript, what would we lose by changing our spring-mvc webapp to only return JSON views and use jQote or jquery-tmpl to do all dynamic bits in the HTML?

Are there any deal breakers in going this route?

Comment: Close as off topic?  Really?  This question covers "software tools commonly used by programmers" and "matters that are unique to the programming profession."  It is a practical, answerable question.  "Are there any deal breakers?"  I'm not looking for debate on particular templating frameworks, I'm looking to see if there are reasons I should avoid this route before I make a big implementation effort.  If you vote to close, please let me know what I need to change in order to keep the question open as I am genuinely interested in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd just lose the ability to take advantage of JSP-based frameworks and templates. If:

- your developer is proficient in Javascript,
- you expect future developers in his place to be proficient as well, and
- you are okay with making javascript a requirement for your site

then this can be a good strategy. The JSON will probably make your AJAX calls a lot faster than returning actual content would do. You'll probably be able to make the site a lot more responsive to user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with injecting content via JavaScript is that search engines cannot see it. They get the page source as it is a load time. If this is an internal application that may not matter, but if it's a public-facing site it could mean very bad things.

You can build entire interfaces from JSON data and a bit of JavaScript on the client. As a technique it works quite well and is fast, but beware of the SEO implications.

Comment: Google has been able to evaluate javascript for some time now.

Comment: excellent point.  In this case the app will require a login, so search engines won't be seeing the content anyway.

Comment: Google can see your content, *if* you use the right techniques, such as URL hashes.

Answer (score 0):

One more point to add:

Say you are loading 300 rows of data to show, then you will have to load 100 row using JS and then show it to user.

It will mimic the streaming features. Content will be shown after request is populated.